# Vanilla JS Sticky Divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a script that will keep divs fixed in their position no matter where they are on the screen when the page is scrolled... Basically, if a div is 50 px from the top, it will stay 50 px from the top of the current window. If a div is 0 px from the top, it will stay 0 px from the top.

I don't want a fixed div because of the cut-off problems they have... So please don't recommended changing the position to 'position: fixed;'...

A script I was working with was essentially doing the following:

```
window.onscroll = function() {

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('sticky_div');
    var doc = document.documentElement;

    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        rect = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect();

        if (doc.scrollTop > rect.top) {
            elements.style.top = doc.scrollTop + rect.top;
        } else {
            elements.style.top - doc.scrollTop - rect.top;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if that actually comes out wrong. I accidentally deleted my original code... Either way, the above method caused to be too laggy and it would jump the headers and divs. Are there any other ways of doing this using less over-the-top processing to do?

elements.style.top = doc.scrollTop; works very well but it won't allow for divs that are positioned elsewhere on the page...

Here's a JSFiddle for the reason why I don't want to use fixed divs (try scrolling horizontally):
https://jsfiddle.net/o27L3uss/

Comment: Have you considered just using css and `position:fixed`?

Comment: What are the "cut-off problems" that fixed elements have?

Comment: "I don't want a fixed div because of the cut-off problems they have..." Just curious as to what your use case is that would keep you from using `position:fixed`?

Comment: If the screen is resized to a point where the elements overflow the screen, the fixed elements will not scroll horizontally, which I do need. All other times I've tried to work with it and got it scrolling with a mix of absolute and fixed elements, it would cut off everything after the default window viewport... Any way around those in that case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you update your question to add some images or mock-ups with what happens with fixed element that you would like to avoid, and what would be the desired outcome?

Comment: I made a JSFiddle for you :) I'll also try to make mockups...

Comment: You can't scroll a fixed element, but an absolute one. And if you want it to stick to the top, `window.onscroll` is the way to go. I say create another fiddle to show your the lag problem, and others "...it would jump the headers and divs."

Comment: I'll try to recreate it. Any general ideas while I work on this?